# How plotting specific vertex labels (such as: c("a", "b", "c")) in Igraph?

Tags: plot, igraph, label, vertex

Why when I tried such as:

```
vertex.label= ifelse(V(graph)$name == c("vertex_name1", "vertex_name2", "vertex_name3"), V(graph)$name, NA)
```

I've received the warning message:

> In V(a)$name == c("vertex_name1", "vertex_name2", "vertex_name3") : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

instead to have the three labels I want?

Comment: Hi Artur. If you would care to add your answer below under your own name, you can accept it, and perhaps get upvotes for it in the future. If you do that, please let me know, so I can delete my own (wiki) answer.

Comment: Yes, of course!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of OP)*.

Got it!

```
vertex.label= ifelse(c(V(a)$name == "vertex_name1", V(a)$name == "vertex_name2", V(a)$name == "vertex_name2"), V(a)$name, NA)
```